# Generic method add new T to list of T

Tags: c#, generics, generic-constraints

I am trying to pass a generic list to a function which will add a new item  to the list. I have the following stripped down example:

```
   private void SetBayNumb<T>(ObservedList<T> bayList) where T : IBaySpec, new()
   {
     var bay = new T();
     bayList.Add(bay);
   }
```

The method calling it has this error:

> The type `T' must have a public parameterless constructor in order to
>   use it as parameter`T' in the generic type or method

Is what i am trying to do possible? I feel it must be as the compiler should not care what kind of list it is - it just needs to call the public, parameterless constructor and add the new instance to the existing list that was passed in.

I guessed the issue was that the interface does not gurantee its implementers will have a public constructor, but even if i give it a concrete class i get this error:

> The type `T' must be convertible to`BayClass' in order to use it
>   as parameter `T' in the generic type or method

Would be very thankful for any pointers.

Comment: you are getting the error because you are specifying a type which does not satisfy the generic constraints.

Comment: Show the method calling it - it obviously is using a type for `T` that does not have a public, parameterless constructor (remember that constructors are not inherited)

Comment: Read the error message it's telling you exactly what's wrong..

Comment: @MethodMan actually I think it does not because there are 2 identically named types involved and it is really hard to distinguish them... (I've added answer that shows the error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your calling code looks like

```
 void Method<T>(ObservedList<T> bayList)
 {
    SetBayNumb<T>(bayList);
 }
```

Issue come from the fact there is no restrictions on `T` in `Method` and hence compiler can't match arguments for `SetBayNumb`.

Note that generic type name is just name - you can pick any name you like and it could help with reasoning about error. Rewriting the same method with differently named generic argument like:

```
 void Method<TArg>(ObservedList<TArg> bayList)
 {
    SetBayNumb<TArg>(bayList);
 }
```

gives better error:

> The type 'TArg' must have a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method

Notice that there are 2 different types involved in the error (which is hard to see when both called the same "T").

Fixes:

- specify the same restrictions on outer generic method (`Method<TArg>(ObservedList<TArg> bayList) where TArg : ... new()` )
- specify `T` on generic class level instead of individual method
- pass concrete class that satisfy both requirements (class for items in the list should implement interface and have parameterless constructor).

Comment: Good tip on renaming T so the error becomes clear. My calling function is as you say but with the IBay constraint... but no new(). Adding that fixed it.

Comment: Let me check i understand why - is it because the compiler can now safely say that the TArg passed to the SetBayNumb function, meets the new() constraint? Otherwise it wouldn't know if the type its being passed has the correct constructor.

Comment: @DBHC - yes.  If TArg has less constraints than T than you can pass more types as TArgs and many of them will not satisfy constraints on T - so indeed compiler need to stop that.

Answer (score 5):

The complaint isn't about the list, it's about `T`. If you have an `ObservedList<MyClass>` and pass it to `SetBayNumb()`, `MyClass` must implement `IBaySpec` and it must have a parameterless constructor: `public MyClass() { ... }`. Why? Because that's what `where T : IBaySpec, new()` says. If you remove the `where` clause, the error will go away, but you will no longer be able to say `new T()`.

Comment: Nice explanation, but I think it is half of the answer - there are two "T" in error message and they are different (my answer tries to show the second half of the problem).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Good point; I gave your answer an upvote for that.